# Using the await operator with Lua

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lua

I'm using [NLua](https://github.com/NLua/NLua) and I'm having trouble with one of my methods that I'm registering. It's a method that returns a Task of bool and it's async, meaning I have to include the await operator before it. However, I'm getting a syntax error when I include it inside my Lua script.

How is it possible to include the await operator inside a Lua script?

**EDIT:** My goal is to make a method that halts it's execution until a response has been set, and then returns the response's result. I believe this has to be done with Tasks, but I'm not sure how to do this.

My old code was:

```
   public async Task<bool> SomeMethod()
    {
        this.Response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        return await this.Response.Task;
    }
```

And then, I would just set Response's Result. However, now that I don't have the await operator anymore, I'm not sure ho wto do this. The scripts don't run on a different thread. I want to be able to stop the execution without halting the main thread.

Comment: You don't *have* to use `await` when dealing with tasks, it's just generally easier than the alternative, which is explicitly adding continuations using `ContinueWith`.

Comment: "The scripts don't run on a different thread. I want to be able to stop the execution without halting the main thread." So you've only got *one* thread, but you want to stop that one from returning until something else has happened? I think you really need to take a step back and think carefully about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet Using my old code I was able to halt the script but not halt the main thread while waiting for the response. I just want to be able to achieve my old code without the usage of the await operator. How can I do it?

Comment: Well we don't really know what you mean by "my old code"... there's a lot that's *very* unclear about this question. But you need to think very carefully about what it means to "halt the script".

Comment: @JonSkeet "The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes. The task represents ongoing work.". Exactly this, taken from Microsoft. By my "old code" I mean that I used the code in the main post and it halted the execution of the method (not the whole thread) and then I just set the response for it using the TaskCompletionSource's Result variable.

Comment: @user3717565: It *sort of* suspends the execution of the method - in that the rest of the method doesn't immediately execute, but the method still returns to the caller at that point. And if Lua doesn't have any similar support, you've still got problems. Basically, you need support for returning an asynchronous result, so that you *don't* block the calling thread. You need to understand the fundamental difference between the synchronous and asynchronous execution models, and it's not clear that you do at the moment... or if you do, it's not clear what the Lua support is like.

Comment: @JonSkeet But the Lua calls the method that halts the execution, meaning it will not continue until the task is complete. Also, would oyu mind answering my question - How do I achieve the same code as above without using the await operator so I can test if Lua is comptabile with this?

Comment: @user3717565: Well you can only use `await` within another async method - so you'd still be returning a task from your method. To be honest, your current `async` method doesn't really need to be async anyway, in that it's mostly equivalent to: `public Task<bool> SomeMethod() { this.Response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); return Response.Task; }` *That* much you can do in Lua...

Comment: @JonSkeet Alright, I removed the async keyword from the declarion and removed the await as well. Now, how would I use ContinueWith to wait for the TaskCompletionSource's response?

Comment: Where? In the Lua? Fundamentally there's still *so* much uncertainty about what you're doing that I can't help you. We don't know anything about what this script is trying to achieve - is it responding to web requests? Something else? Have you looked for Lua support for asynchronous requests?

Comment: @JonSkeet I simply want to return a variable of a boolean type for my script. However, I want to halt the script until the response has been given by the program. That is simply all.

Comment: No, that's not "simply" anything, because that's clearly a *synchronous* operation, which doesn't fit well with the asynchronous data model. I'm afraid I've reached the limit of my ability to help you here. You'll have to either wait for someone with more patience and/or NLua experience, or do more research into NLua's support for asynchrony.

Answer (score 2):

> It's a method that returns a Task of bool and it's async, meaning I have to include the await operator before it.

You don't *have* to use `await` with methods returning tasks - that's just a feature of C# which makes it easier to write asynchronous code. If NLua doesn't have a similar feature, you'll have to make do without it, e.g. by adding continuations to the task with the `Task.ContinueWith` method. It's important to understand that `await` is primarily a *language* feature in C# and VB... it's not part of the framework in itself.

Comment: I see. Can you explain more about ContinueWith and perhaps show me an example? I want a simple way of returning a type of boolean only after the response has been set by another object.

Comment: @user3717565: It's hard to know how to help you without more information about the environment. I mean, you *could* just call `Result` on the task - but that can very easily lead to deadlock with asynchronous code, if the async method has any callbacks which expect to run on the same thread. Fundamentally, waiting until a task has completed before returning is a synchronous approach, which doesn't play nicely with an asynchronous environment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to asynchronous tasks. Basically, I want my Lua script to "halt" when I call "someMethod", until another object has set the response, and then it will return the response. Until I've moved to Lua (from C# and the CodeDomProvider) I've used a TaskCompletionSource and just set the result and used the await operator. I want to return the value AFTER  the response has been set.

Comment: @user3717565: But where's the asynchrony? Why are you using an async method if you basically want a synchronous approach? What thread is executing the code which would set the result in the TaskCompletionSource?

Comment: The main thread handles everything. I want asynchrony because I want to be able to halt the script until the response has been set without halting the main thread.

Comment: I believe you still don't understand what I'm trying to achieve. I want a method that returns a type of boolean only once I set a response to a certain variable from another object. Like, it halts the method until the response has been set, and then returns the response.

Comment: Is the script not executing in the main thread? You're right that I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve, because you haven't described it carefully enough. Do you actually have multiple threads or not? You seem to be assuming we know about your environment when we don't. You should update your *question* to give more details.